# How to sort a html table column by clicking the header [PHP/MYSQL]

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table that is populated by data from a mysql database and i need to be able to click on certain columns of the table to sort them ascending and descending, im not sure how to go about this if i can use php html or javascript , i will attach an image to show what i already have to give a better idea of what im talking about
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHQGi.jpg

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','nba201819'); //The Blank string is the password


$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `teamstats` ORDER BY `teamstats`.`WIN%` DESC");

?>

<table id="teamstats" border ='2'>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>GP</th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>L</th>
    <th><a href='?sortBy=WIN%'>WIN%</th>
    <th>MIN</th>
    <th><a href='?sortBy=PTS'>PTS</th>
    <th><a href='?sortBy=FGM'>FGM</th>
    <th>FGA</th>
    <th>FG%</th>
    <th><a href='?sortBy=3PM'>3PM</th>
    <th>3P%</th>
    <th><a href='?sortBy=FTM'>FTM</th>
    <th>FTA</th>
    <th>FT%</th>
    <th>OREB</th>
    <th>DREB</th>
    <th><a href='?sortBy=REB'>REB</th>
    <th>AST</th>
</tr>
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src='logos/".$row['TEAMCODE']."_logo.svg' width =20 height=20></td>" ;
    echo "<td>" . $row['TEAMCODE'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['NAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['GP'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['W'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['L'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['WIN%'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['MIN'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PTS'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FGM'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FGA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FG%'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['3PM'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['3P%'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FTM'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FTA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FT%'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['OREB'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DREB'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['REB'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['AST'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

    }

    echo "</table>";


?>
```

Comment: Please try https://datatables.net/

Comment: You can do oit both in PHP or in JS. The best solution depends a bit on the situation. 
Are you always showing all te results, or wil you be paginating it?

Comment: its for a college assignment dont want to use plugins or anything else just simple code

Comment: @JasperZelf if you look at the image attached you will see the table i just want to sort the table according to the column that is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various js plugins to help achieve data table sorting such as easyui, datatables etc.

If you only want to achieve it with simple code like you provided, you have to retrieve the `sortBy` variable and put it in your SQL query:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','nba201819'); //The Blank string is the password


if (isset($_GET['sortBy'])) {
    if ($_GET['sortBy'] !== '') {
        $sortBy = str_replace( "`", "``", $_GET['sortBy']);
    } else {
        $sortBy = 'WIN%';
    }
} else {
    $sortBy = 'WIN%';
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `teamstats` ORDER BY `teamstats`.`$sortBy` DESC");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  it working perfect but when i click into the team stats link at the top of the page which brings me to teamStats.php i get the error Notice: Undefined index: sortBy but when i click into one of the table headers it goes away how do i get rid of this?

Comment: cannot thank you enough this has been annoying me for so long much appreciated might actually pass this module now

Comment: You are missing the closing a tag `</a>` for each sorting link

Comment: Made some enhancement hope this helps